# Best external USB drive with transparent Raid-1 support

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, nas, storage

I am in the market for a new NAS/backup system, and came across the interesting [TonidoPlug](http://www.tonidoplug.com/)
.

My last USB external drive (SimpleTech SimpleDrive 1TB) has met its demise, and so I'm trying to figure out what USB drive I should buy. I have not been following HW and gadget news lately, so I'm asking for help from the SuperUser community. :)

Specifically, what is important for me:

- Cheap space (500GB - 2TB usable space)
- USB 2/3 support (so I can easily plug-n-play with the Tonido or laptop)
- Raid1 transparent mirroring (ie. the enclosure takes care of and monitors the Raid array)
- Spin-down and power-saving modes on a timeout; (so I can leave it plugged in and turned on 24x7 without worrying about a fast failure)
- an LED to inform me when one of the Raid drive fails; (otherwise, what's the point?)
- low price tag (don't want to be paying NAS prices)

Are any of these requirements unreasonable? I'm in the dark about which enclosure system is best and does not have a reputation for unreliability.

Thanks in advance for any advice!